# Getting the property value from an array contained in an object that itself is contained in another object

Tags: php, object

I am trying to get the property of an array that is contained within an object that itself is contained in another object.

The code  below is the `var_dump`ed object . i am trying to get the value from the property **identity**     i.e    'identity' => int 101 ..

I put the **'identity' => 101** in asterisk for demonstration purposes only; but the rendered values does not have asterisk. it is the 4th from last line of the code.

I know how to get the values from multidimensional arrays; but not sure about multidimensional objects

```
  object(ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterChain)[373]
  protected 'event' => 
    object(ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterChainEvent)[456]
      protected 'name' => string 'authenticate.success' (length=20)
      protected 'target' => 
        &object(ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterChain)[373]
      protected 'params' => 
        array (size=4)
          'request' => 
            object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request)[194]
              ...
          **'identity' => int 101**
          'code' => int 1
          'messages' => 
            array (size=1)
```

Comment: Where are you trying to use it and what's not working? I mean, from within the AdapterChain class, you could $this->event->params['identity']. It is protected though, so if you have an instance of an AdapterChain class, you won't be able to access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access an object's property the syntax used is `->`, as in `object->property`. To access a given property, it's visibility has to be `public` as opposed to your example, where properties have `protected` visibility.

To access `identity` you need to run `$object->event->params['identity']`, you also need to define a getter function or change your properties' visibility to public.

An example of a getter function

```
public function __get($name){
    return $this->$name;
}
```

Or for a single property

```
public function getEvent(){
    return $this->event;
}
```

Then the syntax used will be ( assuming you define a getter function for `params` as well )

```
$object->getEvent()->getProperties()['identity'];
```